# Convergence of infinite series involving $\frac{\sin(x)}x$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that the infinite series

$$\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$ is convergent.

Please answer so that a Calculus student can understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Dirichlet Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) says that if 
$$
\left|\,\sum_{k=0}^na_k\,\right|\le M
$$
and
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}b_k=0
$$
where
$$
0\le b_k\le b_{k-1}
$$
then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kb_k
$$
is convergent.

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\sum_{k=0}^n\sin(k)\,\right|
&=\left|\,\mathrm{Im}\left(\sum_{k=0}^ne^{ik}\right)\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{e^{i(n+1)}-1}{e^i-1}\right)\,\right|\\
&\le\frac1{\sin(1/2)}
\end{align}
$$
we get that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(k)}{k}
$$
converges.

Comment: Can you explain the bound by 1/sin(1/2)?

Comment: $|e^{i(n+1)}-1|\le2$ and $|e^i-1|=\left|\,2ie^{i/2}\frac{e^{i/2}-e^{-i/2}}{2i}\,\right|=2\sin(1/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Dirichlet criteria, $\frac{1}{x}$ is monotone decreasing to zero and

$\sum\limits_{x=1}^m \sin x$ is bounded.

In response to user61527's question note further that the boundedness can be seen from the well known formula,

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}  \sin i\theta=\frac{\cos \frac{\theta}{2}-
\cos \left( n+ \frac{1}{2} \right) \theta}{2 \sin \frac{\theta}{2} } $$ which gives a bound of

$$\frac{1}{ |\sin \frac{\theta}{2}| } $$

Comment: How would you give a simple explanation that $\sum_{x = 1}^m \sin x$ is bounded?

Comment: @user61527, prove it, say by induction. You can also try the complex numbers approach robjohn writes about in his answer.