# How would the Dirichlet Test for convergence prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{n}}{n}$ does in fact converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been looking for a way to determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{n}}{n}$ converges, and the test that I've most often seen recommended seen is the Dirichlet test for convergence.

Reading the theorem for Dirichlet's test, I have to admit that I'm not having much luck applying the test correctly.  My initial thought is to find some convergent sequence $b_n$ that is convergent and bounds $|\frac{\cos{n}}{n}|$, though then I'm forced to consider something like $\frac{\cos{n}}{n^2}$, and it's still not clear to me how this would be helpful in proving that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{n}}{n}$ converges.

Comment: $\cos{n}={e^{in}+e^{-in}\over 2}$

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: What are two sequences $a_n,b_n$ that you might combine as $a_n\cdot b_n$ to make the sum term of this series such that the two sequences meet the criteria for Dirichlet's test?

Comment: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/831238) might prove useful as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos n \dfrac{1}{n}.$$

The $1/n$ terms are monotonically decreasing to zero and the partial sums

$C_N = \sum_{n=1}^N\cos n$ [are bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/647466). Hence, the series is convergent by Dirichlet's test.